# GAE over quota with billing enabled

Tags: google-app-engine

I deployed my GAE app as module. appengine-web.xml is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>myapp</application>
  <version>200</version>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
  <module>batch</module>
  <instance-class>B1</instance-class>
  <basic-scaling>
  <max-instances>1</max-instances>
  <idle-timeout>10m</idle-timeout>
  </basic-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

But my app returns over quota error.

Request:

```
  https://200-dot-batch-dot-myapp.appspot.com
```

Response:

```
Over Quota
This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later.
```

Actually, free usage of "Backend Instance Hours" (9.00 of 9.00 Instance Hours) is exhausted, but billing status of my app is enabled.

Why I got over quota error? And how to avoid it?

Comment: Have you looked at the budget settings in app engine dashboard?

Comment: Billing Status: Enabled. Maximum Daily Budget is "$0.00". Does this mean unlimitted? or billing disabled?

Comment: it means no budget. Increase it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Outgoing Bandwidth quota must have been exhausted which is 1 GB per day.

Snapshot of App Engine dashboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TApKU.png

You may increase Daily spending limit from $0.00 to few dollars.

Your quota is exhausted because you may be serving image/video from Blobstore, which is part the part of App Engine.
You can use Cloud Storage instead to avoid such over quota issue.